# Like Gamma ray is made of the helium atom, X- rays are made of accelerated charged particles, what are the other radiation in EM spectrum made of?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I just want to know what are microwaves and radio waves made up of, when they travel through vacuum what is it that causes electric and magnetic field vibration.

Comment: A gamma ray is in no way a helium atom - it is a photon/EM wave just like all the others.

Comment: sorry I got it confused it with alpha decay, so just to clarify all the EM radiation are photons but only the ones with wavelength in the visible spectrum are visible ?

Comment: That is correct. Also note there are several different interpretations of what a gamma is. For many, a gamma is a photon generated in a nuclear transition, while x-rays are from electronic transitions. For others, gammas are photons above 10MeV.

Comment: See https://www.e-education.psu.edu/astro801/content/l3_p4.html

Comment: Additionally, the answer to your question(s) can be found simply by searching them up.

Comment: Don't leave an incorrect title on your question!

Answer (score 2):

The entire EM spectrum is made of electromagnetic waves, never accelerated charged particles. The accelerated charged particles might be the source of a wave, but that is as far as it goes.

Gamma rays generally come from something happening in the atomic nucleus. X-rays generally come from something happening in the electrons surrounding the nucleus. Radio waves come from swarms of electrons being repeated pushed into and sucked out of a transmitting antenna at an assigned frequency. In a microwave oven, this frequency is about 2.4 GHz.

It is also common to distinguish these bands by their frequency or wavelength, rather than their source. This can be a source of confusion because it is possible for an atomic nucleus to emit gamma rays of wavelengths that would be described as X-rays or even light. For example, Uranium and Thorium nuclei can emit photons in the ultraviolet band.

Comment: Yes exactly em waves are not made off but they are emitted by say accelerated charged particles